# Unable to open tor folder in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I download tor for Linux OS/Ubuntu 17.10 save the file and ran the code as required according to the website. But unable to open the file and run code: `tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux64-7.5.2_LANG.tar.xz`

however it will not open file to run.

This is the output I'm getting..

```
tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux64-7.5.2_LANG.tar.xz
tar (child): tor-browser-linux64-7.5.2_LANG.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: You want to replace LANG with whatever language you downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

just copy the name of the downloaded file, and replace with the following

"tor-browser-linux64-7.5.2_**LANG**.tar.xz"

it should decompress the file

OR

apt-get install tor